# PySide2 Internal C++ Object already deleted in promoted widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I really need help I'm new in Python programming and in this forum but I have been struggling in making work a promoted widget.

I got a main widget myform.ui

myform.ui:
[image: myform.ui]

With the promoted widget as is shown:
promoted widget window:
[image: promoted widget window]

And a custom one controllcd.ui. With a QDial and a QLCDNumber:
controllcd.ui:
[image: controllcd.ui]

When I run the app the custom widget loads perfectly into the myform widget
running app:
[image: running app]

But when I want to interact with the notch (QDial) rise a RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QDial) already deleted.
I've searching in others similar post and seems to be something with Garbage Collector and the items getting out of scope. But I can't figure out what is wrong or how to do for avoid that error.
I have the code separated in two files, control.py for the custom widget and myform.py for the main widget.

**myform.py**
`

````
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore ,QtGui,QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from mycontrol import MyControl

class MyForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        super().__init__()

        self.loader=QUiLoader()
        self.loader.registerCustomWidget(MyControl)
        self.ui=self.loader.load(file_name)
        self.ui.show()


if __name__=='__main__':
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyForm('myform.ui')
    app.exec_()
```
````

**mycontrol.py**

````
    #! /usr/bin/python3

    import sys
    from PySide2 import QtCore ,QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

    class MyControl(QWidget):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)


            self.loader=QUiLoader()
            self.ui=self.loader.load('controllcd.ui',parent)

            #elements GUI
            self.dial=self.ui.findChild(QDial,'notch')
            self.lcd=self.ui.findChild(QLCDNumber,'lcd')

            #dial setup
            self.dial.setMinimum(0)
            self.dial.setMaximum(100)
            self.dial.setValue(0)

            #Signal
            self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.showdialval)

            self.ui.show()

        #Slot
        def showdialval(self):
            self.lcd.display(self.dial.value())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyControl()
        app.exec_()
    ```
**myform.ui**
````

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>700</width>
    <height>500</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MyFORM</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="MyControl" name="wcontenedor" native="true"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyControl</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>controllcd</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```
````

**controllcd.ui**

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>Form</class>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>500</width>
        <height>500</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>LCD</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="lcd">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>43</x>
         <y>62</y>
         <width>401</width>
         <height>121</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QDial" name="notch">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>150</x>
         <y>230</y>
         <width>191</width>
         <height>171</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
    ```
When I push on the notch then rise the error:
````

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ... line 32, in showdialval
    self.lcd.display(self.dial.value())
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QDial) already deleted.
```

`
If I run only the mycontrol.py works perfectly and I can interact with the notch and displays the numbers in the lcd.
But what I really want is to interact with the promoted widget into the MyForm main widget,
What I doing wrong?

Python 3.6.7 PySide2 5.15.0 Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: Seems to be a bug in pyside2. Remove the `findChild` lines, then replace `self.dial` with `self.ui.notch`, and `self.lcd` with `self.ui.lcd`.

Comment: Thank you thats solved the problem now its working perfectly.  Instead of using findChild, set direclty the widgets: self.ui.widgetname.